# What is the general structure when coding an iOS project if there is any?

Tags: ios

So a few weeks ago I got into Swift and before that I learned a bit Web dev. When learning web development there was always a certain structure to follow for any project. Like specifying where to get the stylesheet from, where to get the JS and that information was put into the head of an html. It is not easy to put my question into words, but is there a general structure for iOS projects? So far I realized that there is always an "import" for example at the beginning of any file to add a framework and then a class. But there is always just one class and all the code goes into that class, why? What else stays always the same for iOS projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can approach developing an iOS project. But generally this is what you need to know.

- All your UI related designs can be implemented in `Main.storyboard` file in your project. Here you can create a `View Controller` and add various UI elements to them like button, labels etc.
- To make sure your `views` look the same across all device screen sizes, you need to use `autolayouts` which is the process of setting `constraints` to the UI elements so that they can be resized according to the screen size of the device they are being displayed on.
- For each View Controller created you have to assign a class file which is a `.swift` file. In this class file you have a function by default called `viewDidLoad()`. This method is executed when the view is displayed on the screen after running the code.
- For each UI element in a `View Controller` you can add `IBOutlets` and `IBAction` to their respective class file.

Here are a few links that can help you more:

- Tutorial for autolayouts: https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started
- Tutorial for Swift programming: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6338-swift-tutorial-part-1-expressions-variables-and-constants
- Get started with iOS: https://codewithchris.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app/

Some other useful links:

- https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/7-things-you-must-absolutely-do-before-writing-an-ios-app-a8bacf710c57
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/477-design-patterns-on-ios-using-swift-part-1-2